# Swift - Typealias dictionary with value that implements a generic protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I want to typealias a dictionary of String keys and values of objects/structs that implements the Equatable protocol. So I wrote this line of code but it gave me error that I didn't know how to go on to fix.

```
typealias Storage = [String: Equatable]
```

I want to use the type [String: Equatable] as a variable in a protocol, e.g:

```
protocol StorageModel {
    var storage: Storage { get set }
    init(storage: Storage)
}
```

Error:

> Protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

[image]
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, the protocol tag isn't required, protocol names are first-class type names and can be used directly:

```
typealias Storage = [String:Equatable]
```

In this case, what the error is telling you is that because Equatable includes `func == (lhs:Self, rhs:Self) -> Bool` and specifically `lhs:Self`, Equatable can't be used except as a constraint on a generic:

```
class Generic<T:Equatable> { ... }
```

Without more details about what you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to use StorageModel, the best I can come up with is:

```
protocol Matches {
    typealias T
    func matches(t:T) -> Bool
}

protocol StorageModel {
    typealias T
    var storage: [String:T] { get set }
    init(storage:[String:T])
}

extension Int : Matches {
    func matches(target:Int) -> Bool {
        return self == target
    }
}

class MyClass <T:Matches> {
    var model = [String:T]()


}
```

Another possibility is to use a generic instead of a protocol:

```
class StorageModel <T:Equatable> {
    var storage: [String:T]

    init(storage:[String:T]) {
        self.storage = storage
    }
}
```

From there you'll need to do some research, dig into the Swift manual, do some googling and see what solves your problem.

Comment: How should I achieve this in another words?

Comment: Because of how Equatable is defined, I don't think you can without defining your own protocol that looks a lot like Equatable, and even then I think you'll run into the same problem. Your best bet might be to define a new protocol that defines an equals method and use that.

Comment: I just updated the question, could you aid me with how I could workaround?